# In cocos2dx using kResolutionShowAll, how can I use the empty borders?

Tags: cocos2d-x, screen-resolution

I'm about to develop a game for android with cocos2d-x and I'm having some issues with resolution. 
I'm using kResolutionShowAll resolution policy to be sure that all of my image is shown in the device. 
But I get a big borders in some devices and I'd like to find out a way to fill those borders with an image, advertisement, or whatever.

I found this: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/20512?r=21066 but it doesn't really work.

I don't know if I choose a wrong policy and maybe I should take kResolutionNoBorder instead. Or maybe I misunderstood something about resolution and I'm not in the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

```
For the support for all devices you can use following code:
**Landscape Mode**

bool AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching()
    {

        // initialize director
        director = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
        EGLView  = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();

        director->setOpenGLView(EGLView);


        CCSize screenSize = EGLView->getFrameSize();
        CCSize designSize = CCSizeMake(800, 480);
        EGLView->setDesignResolutionSize(designSize.width,designSize.height, kResolutionExactFit);


        if(screenSize.height > 480 && screenSize.height < 720 )
        {

            CCSize resourceSize = CCSizeMake(960, 540);
            director->setContentScaleFactor(resourceSize.height/screenSize.height);
            CCLog("Resolution Scale OF Karboon=%f",resourceSize.width/screenSize.width);
        }


        else if (screenSize.height >= 720 && screenSize.height < 800)
        {

            CCSize resourceSize = CCSizeMake(1280, 720);
            director->setContentScaleFactor(resourceSize.height/screenSize.height);
            CCLog("Resolution Scale OF NOTE=%f",resourceSize.width/screenSize.width);

        }

        else if(screenSize.height > 800)
        {
            CCSize resourceSize = CCSizeMake(1920, 1080);
            director->setContentScaleFactor(resourceSize.height/screenSize.height);
            CCLog("Resolution Scale OF Nexus=%f",resourceSize.width/screenSize.width);

        }

        else
        {


         director->setContentScaleFactor(1);
        CCLog("Resolution Scale OF S Advance=%f");

        }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
In the AppDelegate.cpp you can try this.

// initialize director



    CCDirector*  director = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
    CCEGLView*  EGLView  = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();

    director->setOpenGLView(EGLView);


    CCSize screenSize = EGLView->getFrameSize();
    CCSize designSize = CCSizeMake(800, 480);
    EGLView->setDesignResolutionSize(designSize.width,designSize.height, kResolutionExactFit);
```

Comment: KResolutionExactFit will scale the width and the height independently to fit the screen and it'll distort all the images

Comment: I used it images quailty doesn't change that much that you are talking about